# How to download website files and db from an amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: file-sharing, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a website and a laravel application that is hosted on amazon's EC2 service, and I need to download all the website and application files and database(s) locally. How can I do this? Also I don't have an S3 storage with amazon, everything is in a EC2 instance.